# How to call the code from the basis FB when using extending at a Twincat

Tags: plc, twincat

I would like to extend a FB but i need to call the code of the basis FB.

example Code

FB_Basis

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Basis
VAR_INPUT
    bInTest : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    nOutTest    : INT;
END_VAR

IF bInTest THEN
    nOutTest    := nOutTest + 1;
END_IF
```

FB_Test

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Test EXTENDS FB_Basis
VAR_INPUT
    bInTest2    : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    nOutTest2   : INT;
END_VAR

IF bInTest2 THEN
    nOutTest2   := nOutTest2 + 1;
END_IF
```

The Call:

```
FB_Test(  bInTest:= 
        , nOutTest=> 
        , bInTest2:= 
        , nOutTest2=> 
        );
```

If I set bInTest at TRUE I want the Output nOutTest count up but it doesn't.

I can't find information how to handle code from the FB_basis in the [InfoSys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/3537333899.html?id=8892074947972780295) from Beckhoff the just explain the behavior of methods.

I don't know how to call the code, would be thankful for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`SUPER^()`](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tc3_plc_intro/2528837771.html&id=) to call the body of the parent function block. You need to add this to the body of `FB_Test`:

```
FUNCTION_BLOCK FB_Test EXTENDS FB_Basis
VAR_INPUT
    bInTest2    : BOOL;
END_VAR
VAR_OUTPUT
    nOutTest2   : INT;
END_VAR

SUPER^(); // Call the body of FB_Basis
IF bInTest2 THEN
    nOutTest2   := nOutTest2 + 1;
END_IF
```